# Get Attack of Opportunity on Ranger

Tags: feats, opportunity-attack, pathfinder-2e

[Disrupt Prey](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=501) is strictly worse than [Attack of Opportunity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=8), as it only works against your Prey. (Severely limiting the possible triggers)

A [Fighter Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=709) + [Opportunist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=712) feat would take care of that, but Fighter Dedication is mostly useless for a Ranger, except for an extra skill.

Is there a Dedication + feat combination that can be taken by a Ranger (Str 18, Dex 14, Con 14, Int 10, Wis 12, Cha 8), and provides Attack of Opportunity, and something more useful than a skill? The Attack of Opportunity feat should come before level 11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Not an expert at 2E)

### Yes*

The [Marshal Archetype](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=66) appears to access the full version of Attack of Opportunity, albeit delayed. Its dedication feat also gives something more than trained in one skill, although your mileage may vary as to how useful it is.

Note that Attack of Opportunity is a defining feature of the Fighter in 2E, so where other classes get it at all it usually has some caveat, like Disrupt Prey that you linked.
Therefore it makes sense that the Fighter Dedication is the only one that gives access to regular Attack of Opportunity.

You can find all the archetypes that do anything related to Attack of Opportunity by looking at the official reference document and searching for Attack of Opportunity.

https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?Query=attack%20of%20opportunity&Filter=111111111111111&AllTerms=True

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Even if you see yourself as not an expert, we're glad you are here!

It's worth noting that a Charisma 8 Ranger might not get the most out of some Marshal feats, but even then there are enough non-Charisma dependent archetype feats to make it viable.

Answer (score 2):

## Marshal

The [Marshal](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=66) archetype gives you access to Attack of Opportunity as a Feat at level 8. It also gives you Trained/Expert in either Diplomacy or Intimidation and a small aura with a bonus to saving throws against fear for you and allies. As you seem to be a melee fighter, that aura might actually come in handy.

#### other options

all other options (except Fighter dedication, which as you yourself said is not that useful for you) grant you access only at level 12 or later, and for the cost of 3 feats. Also, you don't meet the prerequisites for most of these archetypes (only for Barbarian), but I will list them anyway, to provide a (hopefully) full list of how to get Attack of Opportunity, in case you are flexible with your attributes (or can use attribute increases to meet the requirements)

The options are the [Barbarian](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=2), [Champion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=4), [Magus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=95) and [Swashbuckler](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=43) dedications, but for each of them you need to take the Basic Devotion/Martial Magic/Flair feats (for a level 1-2 feat from that class) and then you can take Attack of Opportunity via the Advanced Devotion/Martial Magic/Flair feats, which allow you to take a feat of up to half your current level from the class. Thus, you need level 12 to have access to the level 6 Attack of Opportunity feats from these classes.

As these do not satisfy your criteria, I won't evaluate the archetypes, but all of them actually provide benefits that are a least nice to have. (Barbarian gives you trained in 1 skill and the Rage action, Champion gives you trained in 2 skills, Magus gives you (very) basic spellcasting and trained in Arcana, and Swashbuckler gives you Panache and trained in one skill.)

Comment: Barbarian dedication can also get access at level 12. Rage alone is of questionable value, but it opens up access to Instinct Abilities at the cost of _another_ feat; not a great choice without Free Archetype, but a fairly compelling one with it.

Comment: Thaumaturge Dedication (for which he does not qualify) + Implement Initiate (weapon) is available at level 6